# Historical Quotes

Tags: history, quote

> Arrange the parts below in such a way that they form 6 history related quotes. Determine the corresponding person for each quote.

<kbd>a myth</kbd> <kbd>a new</kbd> <kbd>a new</kbd> <kbd>a race</kbd> <kbd>becomes</kbd>

<kbd>between</kbd> <kbd>but change</kbd> <kbd>education and catastrophe</kbd>

<kbd>endures</kbd> <kbd>from history</kbd> <kbd>from history</kbd> <kbd>future</kbd>

<kbd>history is</kbd> <kbd>human history</kbd> <kbd>men agree</kbd> <kbd>more and more</kbd>

<kbd>no history</kbd> <kbd>nothing</kbd> <kbd>of</kbd> <kbd>of</kbd> <kbd>only fictions</kbd>

<kbd>past</kbd> <kbd>plausibility</kbd> <kbd>requires</kbd> <kbd>that</kbd> <kbd>that</kbd> <kbd>there is</kbd>

<kbd>to believe</kbd> <kbd>varying degrees</kbd> <kbd>we do not learn</kbd> <kbd>we learn</kbd>

Comment: I was thinking about some of the quotes that **could** have been said and, although it can't be made from the above parts (missing `if` and `no`), decided that a good quote would be `If we do not learn from history, there is no future.`  I wonder if anyone has ever said it?

Comment: @YowE3K Apparently you are the first.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about this:

First

> Human history becomes more and more a race between education and catastrophe
> - H.G. Wells

Second

> History is a myth that men agree to believe
> - Napoleon

Third

> We learn from history that we do not learn from history
> - Georg Hegel

Fourth

> Nothing endures but change
> - Heraclitus

Fifth

> A new future requires a new past
> - Eric Foner

Sixth

> There is no history, only fictions of varying degrees of plausibility
> - Voltaire